# reCaptcha, .NET, Chrome: not working combination

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, webforms, recaptcha

I faced a problem that I wanna share with you, both for documentation and for finding a proper explanation. The issue: **reCaptcha stops showing (and thus working), but only on Chrome**.

**environment**

It's a web site build with .NET 3.5, WebForms, and the official reCaptcha library Recaptcha.web.dll.

**implementation**

```
<%@ Register Namespace="Recaptcha.Web.UI.Controls" Assembly="Recaptcha.Web" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<cc1:Recaptcha id="RecaptchaControl" runat="server" />
```

then, at submit, I check the control using a CustomValidator control.

**output**

A recaptcha box is shown in every browser BUT Chrome, in which a blank space is left. If I try to submit the form, a .NET server error is shown, saying:

> Recaptcha challenge field cannot be empty.

**furher analisys**

Going deep in debug, I got how the dll is actually working: it injects a `<script>` tag referring to `http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=MY_PUBLIC_KEY`. Thus, is seems the core problem is something between Chrome and xss or script injection. Searching google about it, I can't find anything. Even more, the Chrome console doesn't show any error/wanring/info about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**my lucky, loose solution**

After I got frustrated about the issue, I did something both trivial and stupid: I hard-coded a `<script>` tag referring to the `http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=MY_PUBLIC_KEY` I found out during debug. Directly in page. It works as expected: it displays a reCaptcha control in the exact position I put the `<script>` tag. But here's the funny part: after I removed the hard-coded `<script>`, the entire page is working fine, and on other's machines too!

That's all folks, I hope it helps someone else. And, If you can explain me what actually happened, you're welcome ;